# Remove object from the array of LinkedList dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, linked-list

I have tried to remove objects from LinkedList dynamically based on some conditions it removed the first object while removing second object it shows out of range exception. 
I tried to remove objects from end index.At that case also it fails.  I copied the linkedlist to templinkedlist and tried to remove from tempLinkedList by looping original linkedlist. Same exception occurs.
(Exception :: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index)

```
listOfSmtObjects = new LinkedList<SMTObjects>[MAX_LEVEL]; //MAX_LEVEL = 5
LinkedList<SMTObjects>[] listOfSmtObjectsTemp = new LinkedList<SMTObjects>[MAX_LEVEL];

for (int j = 0; j < listOfSmtObjects.Count(); j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < listOfSmtObjects[j].Count(); k++)
    {
        if (listOfSmtObjects[j].ElementAt(k) != null)
        {
            listOfSmtObjectsTemp[j] = new LinkedList<SMTObjects>();
            listOfSmtObjectsTemp[j].AddLast(listOfSmtObjects[j].ElementAt(k));
        }
    }
} 

int totalLevel = listOfSmtObjects.Count();

for (int index = 0; index <= totalLevel -1; index++)
{             
    LinkedList<SMTObjects> SMTobj = listOfSmtObjects[index];
    LinkedList<SMTObjects> SMTobjTemp = listOfSmtObjectsTemp[index];
    if (SMTobj != null)
    {       
        for (int item = (SMTobj.Count()) - 1; item >= 0; item--)
        {           
            if (SMTobj.ElementAt(item) != null /*&& SMTobjTemp.ElementAt(item) != null*/)
            {               
                SMTObjects obj = SMTobj.ElementAt(item);
                if(obj != null)
                {       
                    SMTObjects tempObj = SMTobjTemp.ElementAt(item);
                    SMTobjTemp.Remove(tempObj);         
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to condense your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's way too much going on right now in your code dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is while assigning from original list to temp list,new linked list is created.It should be attached with existing linked list.

```
for (int j = 0; j < listOfSmtObjects.Count(); j++)
{
  for (int k = 0; k < listOfSmtObjects[j].Count(); k++)
  {
      if (listOfSmtObjects[j].ElementAt(k) != null)
      {
          if (listOfSmtObjectsTemp[j] == null)
          {
              listOfSmtObjectsTemp[j] = new LinkedList<SMTObjects>();
          }
              listOfSmtObjectsTemp[j].AddLast(listOfSmtObjects[j].ElementAt(k));

       }
   }
}
```